# Function that returns a new list of all children with allocation VS function that returns a child of that list without allocation

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work out a way to iterate through all the children (including children of children) of an object without creating garbage allocation.

The function I had before was a Recursive function that returned a list.

Now I have two functions one that returns a count and the other that gets the child at a certain index.

I feel like there might be a better way to iterate through all the children of an object

Here is a sample code comparing the recursive list and the recursive count + getAt(index)

```cs
public class MyClassWithChildren
{
    private MyClassWithChildren[] m_Children;

    //With allocation
    public IReadOnlyList<MyClassWithChildren> GetAllChildren(bool includeThis = false)
    {
        var allChildren = new List<MyClassWithChildren>();
        if (includeThis) {
            allChildren.Add(this);
        }

        if (m_Children != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_Children.Length; i++) {
                allChildren.AddRange(m_Children[i].GetAllChildren(true));
            }
        }
        return allChildren;
    }


    //Without allocation combination of count and getAt(index) 


    public int GetAllChildrenCount(bool includeThis = false)
    {
        var count = 0;
        if (includeThis) { count++; }

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Children.Length; i++) {
            count += 1 + m_Children[i].GetAllChildrenCount();
        }

        return count;
    }

    public MyClassWithChildren GetAllChildrenAt(int index, bool includeThis = false)
    {

        if (includeThis) {
            if (index == 0) { return this;}
            index--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Children.Length; i++) {
            if (index == 0) { return m_Children[i]; }

            index--;

            var newIndex = index - m_Children[i].GetAllChildrenCount(false);
            if (newIndex < 0) { return m_Children[i].GetAllChildrenAt(index); }

            index = newIndex;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?
A simple use case for this would be to search if a certain object is a child of another.
Another would be to find all the children that have a certain property value.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I would pass the list as parameter, so all recursive calls can add items to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will is what you're looking for:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClassWithChildren> GetAllChildren()
{
    var items = new Queue<MyClassWithChildren>();
    items.Enqueue(this);

    while (items.TryDequeue(out var result))
    {
        yield return result;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.m_children.Length; ++i) // use for instead of foreach to avoid enumerator creation
        {
            items.Enqueue(result.m_children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This will evaluate the children of a returned value after the external loop has processed it and requests the next one. That means all children are lazy iterated. If your external loop will stop after the first element only this element has been enqueued to the result queue. There is no overhead for enumerators in `m_children` because this code uses a `for`-loop instead of a `foreach`-loop.

If you need the count of all Elements - just use linq: `GetAllChildren().Count()`.